# Bibliography formatting

Tags: bibliographies

All, I have:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Now is the time.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{kn:gnus} David Arnold. {\em Writing Scientific Papers in \LaTeX.} December 31, 2008.
\url{http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math55/WritingScientificPapers/project_latex.pdf}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Couple of questions. How can I turn off the blue highlighting around the url?

And, any suggestions for better formatting this reference bibitem?

Thanks.

Comment: It's normally better to use bibtex (or biblatex) to generate the bibliography and take care of these styling issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that if you don't want URLs to be colored in the references, you probably don't want them colored *anywhere* in the document. If that's the case, be sure to load the `hyperref` package as follows:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
```

The typeset version of the modified MWE looks like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Now is the time.
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{kn:gnus} David Arnold. {\em Writing Scientific Papers in \LaTeX.} December 31, 2008.
\url{http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math55/WritingScientificPapers/project_latex.pdf}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How come your pdf ouput properly do the line break in hyperlink? I have to use linkbreak in hyperref package. My pdf output got out of the page frame. I don't like to use linkbreak because it only works with pdflatex and I would like to use xelatex.

Comment: @Aung - I'm afraid I can't reproduce the issue you mention: Regardless of whether I compile the example code given in the answer with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`, I get the same output, with *or* without the `breaklinks` option set. Are you maybe experiencing issues with other entries? Please consider editing your posting to list some of the entries in question.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend that you consider [`biblatex`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex) for your bibliographical needs- it allows easy customization of your bibliography entries and provides many features and options.

I have converted your MWE into two files: `mybib.bib` which contains the bibliography entry, and `myfile.tex` which contains your document. To get a complete `pdf` you'll need to run

```
pdflatex myfile
bibtex myfile
pdflatex myfile
```

Personally, I prefer to let [`arara`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/arara) do the lifting for me, so you can just run

```
arara myfile
```

on the code below, and you'll get a `pdf`. You can customize the colour of your hyperlinks by consulting the [`hyperref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/hyperref) documentation.

`myfile.tex`

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\addbibresource{mybib}

\begin{document}

Now is the time. 
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

`mybib.bib`

```
@online{kn:gnus,
author= {David Arnold},
title= {Writing Scientific Papers in \LaTeX},
date= {December 31, 2008},
url = {http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math55/WritingScientificPapers/project_latex.pdf}
}
```